# Removed attribute still displaying under Layered Navigation

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation

we have 2 attributes with different attribute code and same attribute name.

attribute code : `"cloth_gender" & "gendernew"`

both have attribute label : **GENDER**

both have dropdown values : `"Boys" , "Girls"`

we are using

```
Atttribute set : "Cloths"
```

we added attribute `"gendernew" to Cloths attribute set`

Initially when uploading the product we assigned  product "P1" to one attribute value [Boys] of attribute "gendernew" ,

later we removed that attribute from attribute set & again added new attribute `"cloth_gender"` to attribute set.

than for "`P1`" we assigned attribute value [Boys] of attribute "cloth_gender"

Now in the layered navigation, both attributes are displaying.

but we already **removed attribute "gendernew" from Attribute set**, but still its displaying in layered navigation.

[image]

Comment: Run reindexing and let me know

Comment: Flush cache and also flush the third party, if any is implemented. Also check if there is any extension related to search and layered navigation is implemented.

Comment: cache is cleared, also we are using extension for both "search and layered navigation"

Comment: @Rohit post your comment as answer, it worked after reindexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run reindexing from Admin panel

Go to : **`System > Index Management`**

Hope this works after indexing